# Navigation view going under toolbar in android

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am trying to add the navigation view but it is going under the toolbar. As the result, first item is not visible and also top three horizontal line that represent navigation view in closed state also not showing. [image: Please check the screenshot]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

   <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_profile"
            android:title="My Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_history"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_history"
            android:title="History" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_payment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_payment"
            android:title="Payment Methods" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_contact"
            android:title="Contact" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
            android:title="About" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_log_out"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>


</menu>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Vitalia"
        android:id="@+id/navHeaderTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Solution tried:**

I try to add         `android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"` in navigation view but it result as([image: screenshot])

How to solve this?

Comment: your app_bar_main.xml layout code please.

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" this will be passed to your app_bar_main.xml layout only.

Comment: @AnkushBist if I will remove the app_bar_main.xml than also same problem exists.

Comment: no i did not mean to remove the layout i want to know the code inside that. as that makes you to display other layout elements

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" remove this code from your drawer layout.

Comment: @AnkushBist thanks bro, it works

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" this was the actual issue?

Comment: yes.. that was the actual issue @AnkushBist

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"  
                app:titleTextColor="@color/White">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.fr.fleetrover.fragment.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer">
    </fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```